# Writing and reading values in binary into an .exe file

Tags: vb.net, binary, exe

i'm trying to write some string and integer values in binary into an exe file then read them in binary when i need.

I wrote the code below to extract the `exe` file from the Resources of my project then open it in binary mode and write the values that i need, and then read them, **but the problem** that i'm facing is that after i write the values in binary, the `exe` that doesn't run anymore, i can still read the values that i wrote in binary just file but the file is not running, if i just extract the `exe` file without writing on it, it will run just normal, so i need a way to make both things work, writing the values in binary and still have the file running normally. "Hope someone will help me with that."

**This is my code :**

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If SaveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
        'Extract the exe file from the resources
        File.WriteAllBytes(SaveFileDialog1.FileName, My.Resources.HelloWorld)

        'Give the file a number to open it in binary mode
        Dim iFr As Short = FreeFile()

        'Open the file in binary mode and write some values on it
        FileOpen(iFr, SaveFileDialog1.FileName, OpenMode.Binary, OpenAccess.ReadWrite, OpenShare.Default)
        FilePut(iFr, TextBox1.Text & ";" & CheckBox1.CheckState & ";" & CheckBox2.CheckState & ";" & CheckBox3.CheckState)
        FileClose(iFr)
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Button4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
    Dim MyString As String
    Dim ReadString As String = My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Desktop & "\HelloWorld.exe"

    'Give the file a number to open it in binary mode...
    Dim iFr As Short = FreeFile()
    FileOpen(iFr, ReadString, OpenMode.Binary, OpenAccess.Read, OpenShare.Default)

    'Setting the length that i want to read and fill it with spaces.
    MyString = Space(LOF(iFr))

    'Reading the values that i wrote and view them
    FileGet(iFr, MyString)
    FileClose(iFr)
    MsgBox(MyString)
End Sub
```

---

**UPDATE :**

This is not possible, so i used [CodeDOM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.codedom.compiler(v=vs.110).aspx) class to recompile the whole `exe` from its source code as a plain text after i replaced the data that i need to store it in.

Comment: You are modifying the executable's file image, adding stuff that is not compiled instructions/compilable code. How do you expect it to run? What is the reason for doing this anyway?

Comment: Thank you, the reason is to store some settings inside the program rather than storing them in a easy-to-edit xml or txt files.

Comment: @VisualVincent so there is no way of doing that?

Comment: Not without _recompiling_ the entire application, no. Windows tries to run the entire file, so if something in it cannot be executed by the processor it will give you an error.

Comment: @VisualVincent Okay, thanks for your help :)

Comment: No problem. Good luck!